# Cordova Xcode build failed "Permission denied"

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

I am trying to build an iOS app using Xcode and Cordova, however I keep getting this error message:

> cordova/lib/copy-www-build-step.sh: Permission denied

Has anyone overcome this problem before?

Answer (score 57):

You can fix it like this also

```
cd platforms/ios/cordova/lib
sudo chmod +x copy-www-build-step.sh
```

This basically gives the file execute permission only instead of chmod 777 which gives it full permission (read, write, execute.) For anyone wanting clarification on what the difference is.

Comment: @Vivek2012 in terminal

Comment: I had to do this in /platforms/ios/MyApp/Scripts but this chmod +x thing worked. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 17):

Faced exact same issue.

I guess git messed up the permissions between windows / mac.

`cd platforms/ios/cordova/lib`

`sudo chmod 777 copy-www-build-step.sh`

Then try to build the project. Worked for me.

Comment: This helped me! My issue was with the file project.pbxproj