# Deploy issue with phonegap project on Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova

Cannot deploy the iOS-phonegap app on a different system. Everytime its giving the error

```
/Users/XYZ/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-gbypfuebotnuihfylyzrfzqypkhe/Build/Intermediates/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/IntermediateBuildFilesPath/MyApp.build/Release-iphoneos/MyApp.build/Script-304B58A110DAC018002A0835.sh: line 2: cordova/lib/copy-www-build-step.sh: Permission denied
```

I have tried changing the permission of file copy-www-build-step.sh, but still it doesn't work. Any help please.

Comment: Did you try this solution? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20200720/cordova-xcode-build-failed-permission-denied

Comment: @GenieWanted Yes I have changed the permissions using the finder --> Get Info, and I guess that's the same thing doing through terminal.