# Ionic Macincloud

Tags: ionic5, apple-developer-account, xcode11, mac-in-cloud

Edited as I found the solution.
It's an Ionic app, which runs completely well on Android. I don't own a Mac, so I'm using Macincloud. Have followed the steps for IOS and can send it, via Dropbox to macincloud and open it (after solving some issues thanks to: https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/1084 ).

But then the build failed. Below I show what I have tried.

[image]

I followed the permissions issue from https://www.educative.io/edpresso/what-is-chmod-in-windows, but it didn't solve it. I don't own a Mac, so I'm completely lost.

By following: https://ionicframework.com/docs/developing/ios the only thing I haven't done is:
npm install -g ios-sim
&
brew install ios-deploy,
because it's a Macincloud and I don't have permission to do that, and I'm not sure if that's the issue.

I also tried locking and unlocking keychain and cleaning xcode project as in [Xcode 10.2.1 Command PhaseScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53289524/xcode-10-2-1-command-phasescriptexecution-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code), but I also don't have permissions in Macincloud to unlock keychain after locking it. :(

Anyone who knows or has dealt with similar issues, I'll be endlessly grateful for your help. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, this part was solved with the chmod +x solution, [Cordova Xcode build failed "Permission denied"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20200720/cordova-xcode-build-failed-permission-denied) just was not sure how to do it as it's Macincloud. Now on to the next challenge :)